# Correct spring for 2018 RockShox XC30

Tags: mountain-bike, parts, fork, suspension

I just got a new Cannondale Trail a few weeks ago (March 2018) and it came with RockShox XC30 100mm travel 29" wheel front fork.  I'm heavier than the average rider so I need the XFirm spring for it.  A quick internet search found lots of sellers selling the 11.4018.010.030 part.  I purchased this and It's too short by about 2cm making my suspension travel substantially lower.  RockShox's [parts guide](https://sram-cdn-pull-zone-gsdesign.netdna-ssl.com/cdn/farfuture/I3gBknA49u_QCZcPaHRAxWKn0zULGD4C_98Ml5YL-Cs/mtime:1488218533/sites/default/files/techdocs/2017_rockshox_spc_rev_b.pdf) reveals that it is for the 2012-2015 (A1-A3) XC30 shock.  The same parts guide lists a 2016 XC30 B1 shock and a different part number for the spring that I can't find listed at any store (11.4018.010.165) (edit: online, in the US).

I don't want to make the same mistake twice so before I ask my LBS to order this part.  Am I getting it right?  Is this the right part or is there a 2018 model year XC30 shock with yet a different set of parts?

Answer (score 2):

My LBS called rockshox.  It looks like I had the right part number but it's moot because they don't make the springs anymore.

Comment: You might get more useful products by talking to a spring manufacturer with all the required dimensions and measurements, including spring rate.

Comment: Your other option might be to craft up some kind of bushing to sit between the end of the too-short spring and the spring stop, to take up the slack.  As a test a 2 cm piece of scrap pipe might be up to it.  Don't use wood for this, not even for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I just ordered this part from [Bike-Components.de](https://www.bike-components.de/en/RockShox/Ersatzfeder-fuer-XC-30-27-5-29-100-mm-ab-Modell-2016-p56811/) in Germany, which I found by Googling for the part number. Rockshox told me this is the correct part for a B-type model fork. If yours is a B then go for it. I did exactly the same as you to start with and found the spring shorter. The part number 11.4018.010.165 is different and has that little bump spring on the bottom like the oem part. But make sure you have a B model fork first.

Comment: At the time I found one place in europe with it.  the link in your post as of today, won't ship to USA :(